# Merge data with same key to one row

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame with several data like this

```
Key     A B C
1       1 2 3
1       4 6 8
1       3 2 1
```

i need to merge these data with same key into one row just like this

```
Key      A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2 A3 B3 C3
1        1  2  3  4  6  8  3  2  1
```

is there any easy way to get this result what i need.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi DimaSan, i have tried to use a loop for this.it does work but seems very Dumb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is only a single group of 'key', one option would be to use `base R`.  We transpose (`t`) the dataset except the first column (`df[-1]`), concatenate to a `vector`, convert to `data.frme` and `cbind` with the first element of the first column.

```
res <- cbind(df1[1,1], as.data.frame.list(c(t(df1[-1]))))
names(res) <- c(names(df1)[1] ,make.unique(rep(names(df1)[-1],3)))
res
#  Key A B C A.1 B.1 C.1 A.2 B.2 C.2
#1   1 1 2 3   4   6   8   3   2   1
```

---

Or use `data.table` i.e. the development version `v1.9.7` if there are many 'Key' elements

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Key~rowid(Key), value.var = c("A", "B", "C"),sep="")
#   Key A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
#1:   1  1  4  3  2  6  2  3  8  1
```

if we have a `data.table` with version < v1.9.7, we need to create the sequence column grouped by 'Key'.

```
dcast(setDT(df1)[, rn := 1:.N , Key], Key ~rn, value.var = c("A", "B", "C"),sep="")
#   Key A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
#1:   1  1  4  3  2  6  2  3  8  1
```

Comment: Obviously there are more than one key... looks like long to wide dupe?

Comment: Thank you, akrun and zx8754, there is only one key column named "key". and obiviously, more the one key for this data frame.for instance, key = 1,2,3,4,5. that means i have group these data for 5 rows

Comment: Hi i have tried on my pc by using your code. but it does not work for my on my data. it says no rowid function and no data there

Comment: @YamPakChing  My solution is based on the input you provided.  The `rowid` is from the devel version of `data.table` which you need to install.

Comment: @YamPakChing  I updated with an option that doesn't need the devel version.

Comment: Hi  Thank you, akrun, i will vote for you. sorry, just one more question. since my true data includes character  and other types. does it work for my data?

Comment: @YamPakChing  It should work for your data as the `data.table` `dcast` can take multiple `value.var` and it can be of different types.